# wordpress wp_list_pages help

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation, wp-list-pages

In my wordpress enviroment, I have a number of pages, and I also have a custom post type called casestudy. I have setup a page-clients.php that has some of it's own content on, I then use the `query_posts()` function to pull in all the posts with the post type casestudy.

When viewing a single case study I wanting to show a nav, this nav needs to contain the links to pages, clients, and case study and underneath case studies I want to add all the posts that are of the custom post type 'casestudy' so far I have following,

`<?php wp_list_pages(array('include' => '154, 136', 'title_li' => '', 'sort_column' => 'ID', 'sort_order' => 'DESC', 'depth' => '1')); ?>`

How can I lists all the casestudy posts also, can it be done with `wp_list_pages()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_list_pages()` function uses `get_pages()`, which accepts a `post_type` argument-array key, so you can use that same argument array key in `wp_list_pages():

```
<?php
wp_list_pages( array(
    'post_type' => 'casestudy'
) );
?>
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the `post_type` value must be a *string*, rather than an *array* (that is, if I'm reading the source correctly); which means that `wp_list_pages()` can only handle one post-type at a time. If you need to list all in one menu, you could try concatenating them:

```
<?php

$pagelist = wp_list_pages( array( 
    'include' => '154, 136', 
    'title_li' => '', 
    'sort_column' => 'ID', 
    'sort_order' => 'DESC', 
    'depth' => '1'
    'echo' => false
) );

$casestudylist = wp_list_pages( array(
    'post_type' => 'casestudy',
    'title_li' => '',
    'echo' => false
) );

$concatenatedlist = $pageslist . $casestudylist;
?>

<ul>
<?php echo $concatenatedlist;
</ul>
```

Codex references:

- [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)
- [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Comment: many thanks the second wp_list_pages is returning false though, even thouse casestudy is post type and has posts belonging too it

Comment: Did you copy/paste the code? Check for a syntax error, that I've since corrected. I left off the comma after `'post_type' => 'casestudy'` in the argument array.

Comment: @Chip Bennett, thanks for the code and explanation. Is there another way to display wp pages and Custom Post Types together that are added dynamically (meaning that I don't know their name)? Maybe there is another function that can handle it instead of `wp_list_pages`? Thanks!